# Error in doing reverse ssh

Tags: linux, ssh

I have just started a job and I am new to using ssh, and I am trying to create a reverse ssh tunnel from the server to my machine at home.

I started by typing

```
ssh -v -f -R port-number1:localhost:port-number2 username@server-name
```

This worked. However, when I type `ssh -v -p port-number1 localhost` it gives this error.

```
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to localhost [127.0.0.1] port 52673.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: SELinux support disabled
Could not create directory '/home/dev/.ssh'.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/dev/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/dev/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/dev/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/dev/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/dev/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/dev/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/dev/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/dev/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Now somehow, my username on the server is 'dev' which is a folder in the root directory, and in the home directory, there is a folder named ubuntu. When I try to locate .ssh in the server, it shows home/ubuntu/.ssh
That might be the problem, but I don't know what to do next as I don't have access to move directories around in the server.

Comment: Sorry, but this Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on  http://superuser.com or another StackExchange site. Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. ***Please*** read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Run this on the remote host:

```
ssh -N user@remotehost -R port:localhost:port
```

Where user is a user on the remotehost, remotehost is the IP/domain of the box you'd like to reverse ssh into, port is the port used (typically 22, but could be arbitrary if not a reserved port), and localhost is literally localhost.

Then try to ssh into the remote host.